# Localizing multiple placeholders where order matters

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to localize a string with various placeholders where in some languages the order matters.

For example the following message where %1$s is song title and %2$s is the song artist. In Japanese the translation requires to show the song artist first an then song title. This is fairly easy with Android since the placeholder specifies the argument number it takes for input.

**Android**

```
<string name="share_listening_msg_2">I’m listening to “%1$s” by %2$s on #xiialive</string>
```

For iOS I'm having a hard time figuring out a solution since there is no placeholder ids like on Android.

**iOS**

```
"share_listening_msg_2"="I’m listening to “%@” by %@ on #xiialive";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use order specifiers pretty much the same way.

Documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/NotesForLocalizers.html

Relevant excerpt:

> If a string contains multiple variable arguments, you can change the
>   order of the arguments by using the “$” modifier plus the argument
>   number

```
/* Message in alert panel when something fails */
"Oh %@! %@ failed!" = "%2$@ blah blah, %1$@ oh!";
```

Comment: Ah! I should have tried that before asking the question :P